# Getting bundled code from Heroku to my local machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku, bundler

Trying to help out with an application that has been on Heroku for awhile.
I cloned the repo to my local machine.

git clone git@heroku.com:whateverapp.git

When I bundle on my local machine I get an error due to this:
gem 'refinerycms-news', '~> 2.0.0', :git => 'git://github.com/guywhoforkedthisapp/refinerycms-news.git', :branch => '2-0-stable'

Essentially the original creator forked a gem and used it in the project but then later deleted it from his public repo.

In the gem.lock file there is a revision SHA, not sure if that can help in this situation.

Curious how I can get that code out of Heroku, it's got to be in some vendors path or something right?

Any thoughts on the best way to get this so I can get the app running locally?

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution to this?

Comment: I wasn't able to find a strategy to get it from Heroku but was able to get with the original developer and get it worked out.